# How can I set up a 24 hours operation with iMacros?

Tags: javascript, c++, imacros

**How can I set up a 24 hours a day, 7 days a week (non-stop) operation with iMacros?**

I Found that code but i can't adapt it my macro. i don't know use visual basic but i setup vbs 2008 today. How can i use that code on my imacros code? Anybody can tell it step by step on vbs. Thanks

```
   'Sample code B
Set iim1= CreateObject ("imacros")
For m = 1 to 5000
   iret = iim1.iimInit()
   For n = 1 to 1000
      iret = iim1.iimPlay ("macro1")
   Next
   iret = iim1.iimExit()
Next
```

Source: http://wiki.imacros.net/Web_Testing#Q:_How_can_I_set_up_a_24_hours_a_day.2C_7_days_a_week_.28non-stop.29_operation_with_iMacros.3F

Comment: to use this code you'll need paid standard edition of imacros

Comment: hmm I have imacros standart license version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about VB solution but JS solution is following.

1. Place `SET !ERRORIGNORE YES` command in macro and `SET !TIMEOUT_MACRO 120` (you can change the time) inside the macro. Then when you call the macro in JS you do it like this.

   iimPlay(macro, 110)

Make sure that the time is less then macro timeout by few seconds. That way macro will restart after each time and script can work a lot of time.

Comment: hmm thanks IceD. I will try it today. Will browser restart time later ? I want use that code because imacros lagging after a certain period of time..

Comment: If browser is lagging then you can use different methods. Like use of command CLEAR to clear cookies.

Comment: hmm thanks but i think we r need browser restart script or code.

Comment: There is a way to do that too. Use C++, make .exe application and killp process firefox.exe plus run macro with the same .exe app. I don't know the code but batch commands can work in this case too.

Comment: hmm thanks i will try batch commands. Do you have sample code ?

Answer (score 1):

```
//this starts firefox
start /d"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox" firefox.exe /AUTO 



//this kills firefox process
pskill firefox.exe

//this command is one version of wait 10 seconds. You can change number 10 into some other for script to wait more then 10 seconds
ping -n 10 127.0.0.1
```

On this link you have examples on how to run iMacros file from bookmarks. So you have couple of examples and you can use them.

http://wiki.imacros.net/iMacros_for_Firefox#Command_Line_Support

Comment: I gave you some up votes so use them well. And ask anything about iMacros you want to ask. Bye.