# iMacro Paid Version?

Tags: javascript, imacros

I want to call an iMacro from my web application(using Javascript) and I was trying to accomplish the same with the free version of iMacro but it didnt work. So do we need the paid version or is that possible with the free variant? Please provide some valuable help/suggestions.

Comment: I don't think iMacro is callable from the web application.

Comment: in general you need paid version for this, but if you manage to open firefox you can start simple IIM script using imacros://run/?m=your-script-name.iim format

Comment: And you have it explained here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14165953/how-can-i-set-up-a-24-hours-operation-with-imacros/14266002#14266002
Just check the bottom post and you will see the links to what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You need the paid version to Record Scripts in iMacros and to use the Scripting DLL / Component. This component is needed to access iMacros APIs.

The trial version should work for 30 days.

And you need the Enterprise version. The Standard won't do it. 
There could be ways around using the Enterprise version / iMacros API, you just have to review your architecture.

Comment: Not true entirely... The DLL files are there if you want to use C# and iMacros. For the scripting with PHP, Python, JavaSript all it takes is FireFox and Addon.